# Crear varios div con su respectiva clase

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

quiero crear una cuadricula en css pero no quiero crear en el html div con la clase card-1 hasta el 100 manualmente. Quiero crear este metodo por medio de un bucle en javascript donde me genere todos las card-1 al card-100 con su respetivo div, no se como aplicar lo logica a esto si me pueden ayudar se lo estaria agradecido. Saludos

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    /*Quiero un bucle que me genere los div class card-1 al 100 automaticamente dentro del container para no crear uno por uno manualmente*/
    <div class="card-1"></div>
    <div class="card-2"></div>
    <div class="card-3"></div>
    <div class="card-4"></div>...
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Para poder apoyarte considera que debes agregar un [mcve] donde expongas que has tratado, así como problemas puntuales que has tenido, aquí puedes leer [ask] para mejorar tu publicación

Comment: Si quieres que sea `card-#` de manera incremental entonces no buscas clases sino ids

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer un bucle que itere de 1 a 100 y vaya añadiendo dinámicamente los nodos con las clases que quieres

```js
let container = document.querySelector('.container')

for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++){
   let div = document.createElement('div');
   div.classList.add('card-' + i);
   container.appendChild(div)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Podes hacerlo tambien con una funcion y un `while` , pasando como argumento la cantidad de `divs` que quieres

- [Document.createElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)
- [ParentNode.append()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append)

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container')

const createCards = (numOfCards) => {

let count = 1 

while(count <= numOfCards){

const div = document.createElement('div')
div.classList.add(`card-${count}`)
container.append(div)
count++

}



}

createCards(4)
```

```css
div{
width:10px;
height:10px;
background-color:tomato;
border:1px solid black
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <section class="container">
     
  </section>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Si las clases son identificadores aplicables a múltiples elementos ¿entonces por qué generar una nueva por cada uno?, ¿no sería entonces mas lógico que sea ids los que se asignen?

Comment: si seria correcto no? pero pidio clases jej , tenes razon , es mas conveniente tener los ids como identificadores unicos

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar con este script

```javascript
const containerOfCards = document.querySelector(".container");
for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  const divElement = document.createElement("div");
  divElement.setAttribute("class", `card-${i}`);
  containerOfCards.appendChild(divElement);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

creo que te puedo dar una respuesta un poco sencilla, sin embargo; checkea los ciclos, pueden funcionarte.

Si tienes VS Code como editor, o alguno que tenga instalado emmet abreviation, puedes digitar el siguiente comando: `.card$*100` y dar enter, te aparecerán los 100 que necesitas.

Sin embargo, también puedes revisar CSS layout grid, puede que te funcione mejor para no tener que crear tantos divs.

Comment: Pero el OP quiere el resultado mediante programación